# Problem of simultaneity

Tags: regression, time-series, multivariate-analysis

I have a question about solving simultaneity in this following case:

Environmental taxes have direct and indirect effect on the change of waste pollution (ΔI). This effect (ΔI) has an indirect influence on environmental taxes in the next year, which may present the problem of simultaneity. However, the annual change of I, which I denote by ΔI, typically varies between 0 and ±7 per cent of the value of I. On this basis, this indirect effect of ΔI has been neglected, because this effect is marginal.  Is this an appropriate, acceptable way for dealing with this issue?

Comment: I am not an expert on time series, but off-hand I'd say "no". The size of $\delta I$ could be small and yet it could have a large effect on taxes.

Comment: I understand your point. However, my time series is only 16 years long and the effects in the environment can be seen on the longer run. Further, I argue that in comparison to other factors (different tax collection efficiency, different tax rates, changes in political priorities within countries, ect.) the effects of the change in impacts is marginal and does not really contribute to the change in the tax sufficiently.

Comment: I didn't say the effects weren't marginal, I just said that the fact that $\delta I$ was small didn't *prove* they were marginal.

Comment: What do you believe would be the best thing to do, to check about this "marginal" effect of dI?

Comment: That depends on the theory underlying its inclusion and also its effects on other parameters. But if there is no reason to include it, it can be left out.